# Not closing os.devnull Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, printing, null

I was wondering if there are problems with not closing the file os.devnull in python. I am aware that normally we need to close files that we open. Nevertheless, I am wondering if it is possible to tread os.devnull as we treat sys.stdout or sys.stderr where we don't close them.

Answer (score 1):

With normal files, you run the risk of losing data when you don't close them due to buffering. This is obviously not a concern for `/dev/null`.

However, while `/dev/null` is *technically* not a regular file but a [device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Pseudo-devices), it uses [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) the same way. You can even inspect the file descriptor in Python using the `fileno()` method:

```py
import os

with open(os.devnull) as devnull:
    print(devnull.fileno())
```

Operating systems limit the number of open file descriptors any single process can have. This is very unlikely to be a problem, but it's still good practice to treat `/dev/null` like any other file and close it for this reason alone.